# Put certain conditions on device version of device in phonegap Android Application

Tags: android, cordova

How can i put certain conditions depending upon the device OS version in a phonegap android application.Like I have tried this:-

```
deviceVersion = device.version;

if (deviceVersion > 2.3){....

        } else {
            ......  
    }
```

But this doesn't works on real devices as the device version is like 4.0.2 etc.

Any Solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    if( ua.indexOf("Android") >= 0 )
    {
      var androidversion = parseFloat(ua.slice(ua.indexOf("Android")+8)); 
      if (androidversion < 2.3)
      {
          // do whatever
      }
    }
```

[Detecting the OS version of iOS and Android in the browser](http://jimbergman.net/detecting-os-version-of-ios-and-android-in-the-browser/)

Comment: here u used userAgent however can we use device.version for this